# Move an IWeb Element from one list to another and comparing their count using Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Objective is to create a automated test for QA which asserts that one List is different from another by the count of elements/items which they possess by using the Selenium WebDriver.

This is the webpage for getting the lists :  http://demoqa.com/sortable/ and then Connect Lists

This is the code :

```
[Test]

//Arrange

_driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://demoqa.com/sortable/"); 

List<IWebElement> sortableListOne = _driver.FindElements(By.Id("sortable1")).ToList();

IWebElement sortableListOneFifth = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//*[@id=""sortable1""]/li[5]"));

List<IWebElement> sortableListTwo = _driver.FindElements(By.Id("sortable2")).ToList();

IWebElement sortableListTwoForth = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//*[@id=""sortable2""]/li[4]"));

//Act

Actions action = new Actions(_driver);
            action.DragAndDrop(SortableListOneFifth, SortableListTwoForth)
                .Perform();
```

So i tried :

```
//Assert
        var list1 = _sortPage.SortableListOne.Count;
        var list2 = _sortPage.SortableListTwo.Count;

        list1.Should().NotBe(list2);
```

The error message :

```
Message: Did not expect list1 to be 1.
```

Both lists are returning the count of 1 so they are always the same and not returning the IWeb elements of lists.

Do I need to create a for cycle to iterate each list ? Ideas on how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks `sortableListOne`  and `sortableListTwo` WebElements are identified using id and only one matched elements are found and hence it is returning as 1.

Please find the `sortableListOne`  and `sortableListTwo` WebElements  using the xpath as below and it

**Code:**

```
List<IWebElement> sortableListOne = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@id='sortable1']/li")).ToList();

List<IWebElement> sortableListTwo = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@id='sortable2']/li")).ToList();
```

After changing the sortableListOne`and`sortableListTwo` element locator, please use the below in your test method and it will return the correct count

```
var list1 = _sortPage.SortableListOne.Count;
var list2 = _sortPage.SortableListTwo.Count;

list1.Should().NotBe(list2);
```

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. Please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

`sortableListOne` and `sortableListTwo` contains one element, the items container. To get list of all the items you need to locate the `<li>` tags under each one, **after** the drag and drop action. Changing the web page doesn't effect previously located elements and you might get `StaleElementReferenceException`

```
Actions action = new Actions(_driver);
action.DragAndDrop(SortableListOneFifth, SortableListTwoForth).Perform();

List<IWebElement> sortableListOne = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath(@"//*[@id='sortable1']/li")).ToList();
List<IWebElement> sortableListTwo = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath(@"//*[@id='sortable2']/li")).ToList();

var list1 = _sortPage.SortableListOne.Count;
var list2 = _sortPage.SortableListTwo.Count;

list1.Should().NotBe(list2);
```